# why do we need to use interfaces and then again respective impl classes instead of direct impl classes in application development

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have seen in many applications as, user defined interfaces will be defined and then their respective implementation classes are available. 
Then again we will call those implementation classes methods from interface level.

We we are following this approach? is there any significant idea behind this?

why can't we go with direct classes implantation without interfaces?

Thank you so much in advance, if some one elaborate this clearly.

Comment: [What does it mean to “program to an interface”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)

Answer (score 0):

An interface provides a level of indirection between a **client** (a class that uses the interface) and the implementation details of a concept. For example, if we wanted to create a persistence layer that stores data in a database, we could simply create a class that performs the persistence to a specific type of database (say, *A*). The problem is that the rest of our system that uses the class for database *A* is now tied to the implementation details of database *A*.

If we decide later to use database *B*, swapping out the *A* class for the *B* class may be difficult. If, instead, we created an interface, `Repository`, that abstracts the common details of both databases *A* abd *B*, we could provide a simplified facade to persisting objects. Then we can create an implementation of `Repository` for *A* and *B*:

```
public interface Repository {
    public void save(Object object);
    public Object findById(long id);
}

public class ADatabaseRepository implements Repository {

    @Override
    public void save(Object object) {
        // ... save object in database A ...
    }

    @Override
    public Object findById(long id) {
        // ... find object with id in database A ...
    }
}

public class BDatabaseRepository implements Repository {

    @Override
    public void save(Object object) {
        // ... save object in database B ...
    }

    @Override
    public Object findById(long id) {
        // ... find object with id in database B ...
    }
}
```

Then some client class, `Client`, can depend on the interface `Repository`, rather than on some specific implementation class:

```
public class Client {

    private final Repository repository;

    public Client(Repository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        Object desiredObject = repository.findById(1);
        // ...
    }
}
```

This allows us to supply any implementation of `Repository` to `Client` at runtime without changing any code in `Client`:

```
ADatabaseRepository a = new ADatabaseRepository();
BDatabaseRepository b = new BDatabaseRepository();

// Create with A
Client clientA = new Clinet(a);

// Create with B
Client clientB = new Client(b);
```

**Warning**: Although interfaces are very useful, they can be overused. If there is a situation where indirection is not needed, such as when there will likely only be a single implementation of some interface, then a class can be used in place of an interface and class (although the decision to do so is a judgment call; there is no hard-and-fast rule). Using an interface where a class would do creates unneeded complexity.

For more information on common use cases for interfaces, see the following:

- [Strategy Pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/strategy)
- [Observer Pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/observer)
- [Composite Pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/composite)

Comment: Thank you @Justin Albano